# Electron application .package .js file

Tags: node.js, electron

I'm working with a electron application. I want to call a file during installation of the application. Will it work if I call the file from scripts property of package.json file ??

This is inside my package.json file

```
Scripts { 

"Start" : electron-forge start 
"Install" : "node install.js " 

}
```